# http.Handle("/", websocket.Handler(EchoServer) Can EchoServer Get another parameter other than ws?

Tags: websocket, go

I have opened a websocket server to send data to web component,

```
func WebSocketServer() {
    http.Handle("/", websocket.Handler(Echoserver))
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil)
    CheckError(err)
}
```

I would like to pass an additionnal argument (msg, of type String) to the handlerfunction (Echoserver).

```
func Echoserver(ws *websocket.Conn, msg String) {
    fmt.Println("Client Connected")
         _ := websocket.JSON.Send(ws, msg);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this with the syntax above?
How do you call Echoserver with the additionnal parameter ?

Comment: BTW, this is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773322/passing-in-parameters-to-a-http-handlerfunc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume what you want here is a consistent `string` parameter that is returned for all connections to /. There are a couple of approaches I've used. (None of these specific code samples have been tested; I can pull some real code if they don't compile.)

One is to let the data be the receiver. I use this a most often with a struct, but any parameter will do. This only works for a single parameter (but you could of course put multiple parameters in a struct). I like this approach when the parameter is "object like." (Generally a struct that has other methods on it.)

```
type echoStuff string

var hey echoStuff = "Hey!"

http.Handle("/", websocket.Handler(hey.EchoServer))
err := http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil)
CheckError(err)

func (msg echoStuff) Echoserver(ws *websocket.Conn) {
  fmt.Println("Client Connected")
   _ := websocket.JSON.Send(ws, msg);
}
```

Another way is with a closure. I like this approach when the parameter is "data like." (Something like a string or other simple data. Note how this approach doesn't require creating a local type.)

```
func WebSocketServer() {
  http.Handle("/", echoHandler("Hey!"))
  err := http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil)
  CheckError(err)
}

func echoHandler(msg string) websocket.Handler {
  return func(ws *Conn) {
    Echoserver(ws, msg)
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me thank you! but my server written in golang crashes. this is the error  "golang panic: http: multiple registrations for /"

Comment: That generally means you're calling `http.Handle()` multiple times with `/` as the first parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be able to pass a parameter that way since a **[`websocket.Handler`](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket#Handler)** expect a function with a specific signature.

```
func(*Conn)
```

This is probably a situation where **channel** are called for.
See [this example for instance](https://github.com/tenntenn/golang-samples/blob/62880786e061c55412d7af4b114d6e3a5ead9456/websocket/websocket-chat/chat/server.go#L49-L73):

First, your handler function creates a channel:

```
yourHandlerFunction := func(ws *websocket.Conn) {
  client := NewClient(ws, self)
  self.addClient <- client
  client.Listen()
  defer ws.Close()
}
```

(Here, a ["Client" is a struct](https://github.com/tenntenn/golang-samples/blob/62880786e061c55412d7af4b114d6e3a5ead9456/websocket/websocket-chat/chat/client.go#L9-L14) which includes a channel and a pointer to the `websocket.Conn`)

Then the server waits for a new client, and pass a message that way:

```
for {
  select {

    // Add new a client
    case c := <-self.addClient:
      log.Println("Added new client")
      self.clients = append(self.clients, c)
      for _, msg := range self.messages {
        c.Write() <- msg
    }
```

Finally, the [Client can receive the message](https://github.com/tenntenn/golang-samples/blob/62880786e061c55412d7af4b114d6e3a5ead9456/websocket/websocket-chat/chat/client.go#L55-L74), and then make the JSON call:

```
// Listen write request via chanel
func (self *Client) listenWrite() {
  log.Println("Listening write to client")
  for {
    select {

      // send message to the client
      case msg := <-self.ch:
        log.Println("Send:", msg)
        websocket.JSON.Send(self.ws, msg)

      // receive done request
      case <-self.done:
        self.server.RemoveClient() <- self
        self.done <- true // for listenRead method
      return
    }
  }
}
```